# How can I reuse a Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am using a Common Table Expression for paging:

```
with query as (
  Select Row_Number() over (Order By OrderNum ASC) as TableRowNum,
         FirstName,
         LastName
  From   Users
)
Select * from query where TableRowNum between 1 and 25 Order By TableRowNum ASC
```

Immediately after making this query, I make make an almost identical query in order to retrieve the total number of items:

```
with query as (
  Select Row_Number() over (Order By OrderNum ASC) as TableRowNum,
         FirstName,
         LastName
  From   Users
)
Select Count(*) from query
```

I have tried combining these together (ie: define the CTE, query the data and then query the Count, but when I do this, I get an error message "Invalid object name 'query'" in response the the second query (the Count).

Is there any way to combine these two queries into one, to save a round-trip to the DB?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you do not require them in 2 different queries, you can try

```
;with query as (
  Select Row_Number() over (Order By UserID ASC) as TableRowNum,
         FirstName,
         LastName
  From   Users
),
totalCount AS (
    SELECT COUNT(1) Total FROM query
)
Select  query.*,
        Total
from    query, totalCount 
where   TableRowNum 
between 1 and 25 
Order By TableRowNum ASC
```

If you do require 2 different queries, rather use a table var

```
DECLARE @User TABLE(
        TableRowNum INT,
        FirstName VARCHAR(50),
        LastName VARCHAR(50)
)
;with query as (
  Select Row_Number() over (Order By UserID ASC) as TableRowNum,
         FirstName,
         LastName
  From   Users
)
INSERT INTO @User
SELECT  TableRowNum,
        FirstName,
        LastName
FROM    query

SELECT  *
FROM    @User
where   TableRowNum 
between 1 and 25 
Order By TableRowNum ASC

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @User
```

Comment: @Scott Rippey, I find CTEs eaiser to read, reuse and maintain.

Comment: Oh thanks. In your first code block, you use a CTE to get the total and to get the results, which makes perfect sense. But I get an error when I try to query a CTE twice. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: +1. I am working with unions on three large tables (20 million plus) and the first example resulted in the query taking twice as long to execute.  I used the second example and the performance is very close to the query without the total; there's a small performance hit to scan the in memory table, but it's small (about a second).

Answer (score 1):

**You can do that like this :**

```
with query as (
   Select 
 COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS TableTotalRows,
 Row_Number() over (Order By OrderNum ASC) as TableRowNum,
     FirstName,
     LastName
  From   Users
)
```

Comment: Sometimes the query itself can have aggregate functions in it (FirstName, LastName was just a simple example), so adding `Count(*)` as a column would not be a reliable solution.