# Reuse results from SQL Server common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I have a query to retrieve all the modules and child modules for a page, using a common table expression. Is it possible to use the results from the cte more than once?

example

```
WITH top_level_modules (
[AppContentModuleID]
,[SortIndex]
,[ContentHolderName]
,[OwnerType]
,[AppContentModuleGuid]
,[parent_AppContentModuleID]
,[ModuleID]
,[RenderIDTag]
,[WrapperType]
,[Level]
)
AS
( 
SELECT amcp.[AppContentModuleID]
    ,amcp.[SortIndex]
    ,amcp.[ContentHolderName]
    ,1
    ,amc.[AppContentModuleGuid]
    ,amc.[parent_AppContentModuleID]
    ,amc.[ModuleID]
    ,amc.[RenderIDTag]
    ,amc.[WrapperType]
    ,0 AS [Level]
FROM [dbo].[application_module_content_page] amcp
INNER JOIN [dbo].[application_module_content] amc on amcp.[AppContentModuleID] = amc.[AppContentModuleID]
WHERE amcp.[PageID] = @PageID
UNION
SELECT amcm.[AppContentModuleID]
    ,amcm.[SortIndex]
    ,amcm.[ContentHolderName]
    ,2
    ,amc.[AppContentModuleGuid]
    ,amc.[parent_AppContentModuleID]
    ,amc.[ModuleID]
    ,amc.[RenderIDTag]
    ,amc.[WrapperType]
    ,0
FROM [dbo].[application_module_content_masterpage] amcm
INNER JOIN [dbo].[application_module_content] amc on amcm.[AppContentModuleID] = amc.[AppContentModuleID]
WHERE amcm.[AppMasterPageID] = @MasterPageID
),
child_modules AS 
(
SELECT tlm.[AppContentModuleID]
    ,tlm.[SortIndex]
    ,tlm.[ContentHolderName]
    ,tlm.[OwnerType]
    ,tlm.[AppContentModuleGuid]
    ,tlm.[parent_AppContentModuleID]
    ,tlm.[ModuleID]
    ,tlm.[RenderIDTag]
    ,tlm.[WrapperType]
    ,tlm.[Level]
FROM top_level_modules tlm
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    amc.[AppContentModuleID]
    ,CASE WHEN amc.[SortIndex] IS NULL THEN tlm.[SortIndex] ELSE amc.[SortIndex] END
    ,null
    ,3
    ,amc.[AppContentModuleGuid]
    ,amc.[parent_AppContentModuleID]
    ,amc.[ModuleID]
    ,amc.[RenderIDTag]
    ,amc.[WrapperType]
    ,[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
FROM [dbo].[application_module_content] amc
INNER JOIN child_modules tlm on tlm.[AppContentModuleID] = amc.[parent_AppContentModuleID]
)
SELECT * 
FROM child_modules cm
ORDER BY cm.[OwnerType]
, cm.[Level]
, cm.[SortIndex]

SELECT apcs.[StyleType] 
    ,apcs.[StyleName]
    ,apcs.[StyleValue]
FROM child_modules cm
INNER JOIN dbo.[application_module_content_style] apcs 
on cm.AppContentMdouleID = apcs.AppContentMdouleID
```

The first select works, but the second select throws up the error "Invalid object name 'child_modules'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the `WITH common_table_expression` manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and *defined within the execution scope of a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement*.

So, no, you can't extend the scope of the CTE beyond the SELECT statement it was defined in. You will have to store the result in a temporary table or table valued variable if you want to use the result more than once.

Comment: thanks for the answer, have been searching around and missed that! my bad

Comment: you can see an example of the implementation with table var here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5938963/570191

Answer (score 2):

You will need split child_modules CTE into two CTE's.

The first one containing the first SELECT of the current child_modules CTE, then use a second CTE that builds upon child_modules.

Your final SELECT would then use the third CTE instead of child_modules.

Answer (score 0):

Use like following :

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetAllData] 
(
    @UserId int    
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN  
(
    WITH UserPRecursive AS
    (   
    SELECT u.userid,u.OverrideID
    FROM UserOverride u where OverrideID=@UserId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.userid,C.OverrideID
    FROM UserOverride AS C INNER JOIN UserPRecursive AS cr
    ON C.OverrideID = cr.userid 
    )   
    , UserCRecursive AS
    (   
    SELECT u.userid,u.OverrideID
    FROM UserOverride u where UserID=@UserId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.userid,C.OverrideID
    FROM UserOverride AS C INNER JOIN UserCRecursive AS cr
    ON C.userid = cr.OverrideID 
    )
    SELECT distinct CR1.userid as userId FROM UserPRecursive AS CR1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT distinct cr2.OverrideID as userId FROM UserCRecursive AS CR2 
    UNION ALL
    select userid from [User] where UserID=@UserId
)
```